# ORMLite orderBy multiple columns not working

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-order-by, ormlite

I'm having an issue with ordering a list of objects that I'm querying through ORMLite where I want to order by 2 separate columns. I want to order by the Priority being the lowest and the Count being the highest. However it seems as if the query is only accepting the last orderBy that I set instead of both. For example here are the two queries and their results:

```
QueryBuilder<CategoryData, Integer> queryBuilder4 = dao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder4.orderBy(CategoryData.FACE_COUNT_COLUMN_NAME, false);
queryBuilder4.orderBy(CategoryData.PRIORITY_COLUMN_NAME, true);
Log.d(TAG, "4 Query returns:"+ queryBuilder4.query().toString());
```

And it's output:

```
name=Blues, db=158, count=3, priority=1, firstLookDbID=6
name=Greens, db=165, count=3, priority=8, firstLookDbID=9
name=Blacks, db=157, count=1, priority=0, firstLookDbID=2,...
```

Second code block:

```
QueryBuilder<CategoryData, Integer> queryBuilder5 = dao.queryBuilder();
queryBuilder5.orderBy(CategoryData.PRIORITY_COLUMN_NAME, true);
queryBuilder5.orderBy(CategoryData.FACE_COUNT_COLUMN_NAME, false);
Log.d(TAG, "5 Query returns:"+ queryBuilder5.query().toString());
```

And it's output:

```
name=Blacks, db=157, count=1, priority=0, firstLookDbID=2
name=Blues, db=158, count=3, priority=1, firstLookDbID=6
...
name=Greens, db=165, count=3, priority=8, firstLookDbID=9...
```

Notice the only difference between the two queries is the order I put the orderBys. However they give me 2 different ordered sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query (queryBuilder4) orders the result by FACE_COUNT_COLUMN_NAME in a descendent way, if  exists the same value, in this case “count = 3”,  the query uses the PRIORITY_COLUMN_NAME to order the result by “priority” in an ascendent way.

The second query (queryBuilder5) orders the result by PRIORITY_COLUMN_NAME in a ascendent way, but not exists the same value in “priority”, for this reason the "order by FACE_COUNT_COLUMN_NAME" is ignored and the result is diferent to the first query.

Comment: OH! I understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> Notice the only difference between the two queries is the order I put the orderBys. However they give me 2 different ordered sets.

Right.  This is expected behavior.  In SQL, the `ORDER BY` clauses are processed in specific order.  To quote the [`QueryBuilder.orderby(...)` javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#orderBy(java.lang.String,%20boolean)) with emphasis:

> Add "ORDER BY" clause to the SQL query statement. This can be called multiple times to add additional "ORDER BY" clauses. **Ones earlier are applied first**.

So in the first instance, the `FACE_COUNT_COLUMN_NAME` is ordered first descending.  If the count is equal, then the `PRIORITY_COLUMN_NAME` is ordered ascending.  In the second, the priority is first ordered ascending.  If the priority is equal, the the count is ordered descending.